# How to form multiple Join Conditions sql query in Sqlkata

Tags: c#, sqlkata

I am trying to build the Sql Query using by using Sqlkata.I am able to build the correct sql query for one join condition ,but for And Condition i am facing issues

```
var empDeptQuery = new Query("employee");
empDeptQuery.Select("employee.Name", "dept.Deptname");
empDeptQuery.Join("dept", join => join.On("employee.deptid", "dept.deptid"));          

SqlResult empDeptSqlKataQuery = compiler.Compile(empDeptQuery);
```

Final Query -empDeptSqlKataQuery.Sql is

```
SELECT [employee].[Name], [dept].[Deptname] FROM [employee] 
INNER JOIN [dept] ON ([employee].[deptid] = [dept].[deptid])
```

i want to add on more condition  in join clause like in the following way.

```
SELECT [employee].[Name], [dept].[Deptname] FROM [employee] 
INNER JOIN [dept] ON ([employee].[deptid] = [dept].[deptid] And [employee].[empdeptname]=[dept].[departmentName])
```

i have tried this but didn't get what i expected

```
var empDeptQuery = new Query("employee");
empDeptQuery.Select("employee.Name", "dept.Deptname");
empDeptQuery.Join("dept", join => join.On("employee.deptid", "dept.deptid"));
empDeptQuery.Join(empDeptQuery, join => join.On("employee.empdeptname", "dept.departmentName"));

 SqlResult empDeptSqlKataQuery = compiler.Compile(empDeptQuery);
```

Final Sql query with the above approach :

```
SELECT [employee].[Name], [dept].[Deptname] FROM [employee] 
INNER JOIN [dept] ON ([employee].[deptid] = [dept].[deptid])
INNER JOIN (SELECT [employee].[Name], [dept].[Deptname] FROM [employee] 
INNER JOIN [dept] ON ([employee].[deptid] = [dept].[deptid])) ON ([employee].[empdeptname] = [dept].[departmentName])
```

Please let me know how to fix the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `On` or `WhereX` methods as needed, for example

```
new Query("employee")
    .Select("employee.Name", "dept.Deptname")
    .Join("dept", 
        j => j.On("employee.deptid", "dept.deptid")
            .On("employee.countryid", "dept.countryid")            
    )
```

Note that `On` is just an alias for the `WhereColumns` method, so all `WhereX` methods works in this context also

Answer (score 0):

When your on conditions are not constant, you can just define this ext method

```
internal static class SqlKataExt
{
    internal static Join On(this Join j, List<Tuple<string, string>> onConditions, string op = "=")
    {
        foreach (var o in onConditions)
        {
            j = j.On(o.Item1, o.Item2);
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

where `onConditions` represents the list of paired conditions.

eg: `{{"t1.col1", "t2.col1"}, {"t1.col2", "t2.col2"}...}`

Then use it like this

```
            SqlKata.Query query = new SqlKata.Query();
            query = query.LeftJoin(inner, j => j.On(onConditions));
```